# Can we post an array of objects with knex?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm using knex with node and I was thinking of making a field in the migration that would take an array of objects. I know simple stuff like

```
.string("bla")
.notNullable()
```

and so on, looking in the documentation can't seem to find it

wanting something like

```
.array_of_objects //field name

knex.schema.createTable('users', function (table) {
  table.increments();
  table.string('name');
  table.timestamps();

//example
table.array
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With `table.specificType` you can create which ever type of database column you like. You need to check from your database, which kind of columns it supports.

It would make easier to answer the question if you could tell what kind of SQL queries you are after. To be able to use knex, you need to know SQL. Knex will never abstract SQL away.

If you are looking for a database library for node.js that abstracts SQL away you might like to checkout `sequelize`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the post with the specificType. From what I saw PG didn't have an array of objects field, but did have an array of strings field. I ended up taking my array of objects and separating it into two string arrays one named keys and the other values. I stored both of those arrays in the database. Then when I did a get request I took the two arrays joined them together into an array of objects with some javascript tacking. Seems to do the trick.